# What does εὗρεν mean in Luke 4:17? Finding by luck, chance or investigation?

Tags: jesus

> And there was delivered unto him the book of the prophet Esaias. And *when he had opened the book*, he **found** the place where it was written, KJV  Luke 4:17.

What does εὗρεν mean in Luke 4:17? Finding by luck, chance or investigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pertinent verb here is εὑρίσκω (heuriskó) which has come directly into English in the form of the adjective "heuristic" with almost identical meaning.  According to BDAG, this verb has three shades of meaning:

1. **to come upon something either through purposeful search or accidentally, *find***,

- (a) after seeking: eg, Matt 7:7, Luke 11:9, 2 Tim 1:17, Matt 12:43, 26:60, Mark 14:55, Luke 11:24, 13:6, John 7:34, 36, Rev 9:6, Mark 1:37, Luke 2:45, 2 Cor 2:13, Matt 7:14, 13:46, 18:13, Luke 24:3, etc.
- (b) accidentally, without seeking, eg, Matt 18;28, 27:32, John 1:41, 43, 45, 5:14, 9:35, Acts 13:6, 18:2, 19:1, 28:14, Matt 13:44, 17:27, John 12:14, etc

2. **to discover intellectually through reflection, observation, examination, *find, discover***, eg, Rom 7:21, Acts 13:28, 23:9, 29, 24:20, Rev 3:2, Luke 23:2, John 18:38, 19:4, 6, 2 Peter 3:10, Acts 19:19, 27:28, Luke 5:19, etc
3. **to attain a state or condition, *find (for oneself), obtain***. The middle voice is used in this sense; in the NT it occurs in this sense only, eg, Heb 4:16, 9:12, 12:17, Matt 10:39, 16:25, 11:29, Acts 7:46, Luke 1:30, 2 Tim 1:18.

Thus, in Luke 4:17, Jesus appears to deliberately find the passage after "unrolling the scroll", ie, He read by searching it out; thus He makes the passage in Isa 61:1, 2 the keynote of His earthly ministry.

Note the comments in the Pulpit commentary:

> Verse 17. - And there was delivered unto him the Book of the Prophet
> Esaias. In the sabbath service there were two lessons read. The first
> was always taken from the Pentateuch (the Law). The five books of
> Moses were written on parchment, (usually) between two rollers, and
> the day's lesson was left unrolled for the reader's convenience. The
> Prophets were on single rollers, no special portion being left open.
> It has been suggested that the great and famous Messianic passage read
> by our Lord was the lesson for the day. This is quite uncertain;
> indeed, it is more probable that Jesus, when the roll of Isaiah was
> handed to him by the ruler of the synagogue, specially selected the
> section containing this passage. Luke 4:17

Answer (score 1):

Books were not in Codex form until about the third or fourth century.  Jesus was handed a scroll.  Thus, *found* meant he unrolled it to the passage.  This would be expected.  Otherwise, they would always read the beginning of the book.  A.T. Robertson wrote that we don't know is if that was the passage the synagogue expected him to read or the one he chose.  However, C.S. Keller wrote that regular assigned passages in the synagogue wasn't until a later date.  Thus, Jesus probably chose the passage he turned to.

> Opened (ἀνοιξας [anoixas]). Really it was unrolled (ἀναπτυξας [anaptuxas]) as Aleph D have it. But the more general term ἀνοιξας [anoixas] (from ἀνοιγω [anoigō], common verb) is probably genuine. Ἀναπτυσσω [Anaptussō] does not occur in the N. T. outside of this passage if genuine. Found the place (εὑρεν τον τοπον [heuren ton topon]). Second aorist active indicative. He continued to unroll (rolling up the other side) till he found the passage desired. It may have been a fixed lesson for the day or it may have been his own choosing. At any rate it was a marvellously appropriate passage (Isa. 61:1 and 2 with one clause omitted and some words from 58:6).
> --
> Robertson, A. T. (1933). *Word Pictures in the New Testament* (Lk 4:17). Broadman Press.

> 4:17. Synagogues later followed regular lectionary readings, but in this period readers had more freedom to choose the reading from the Prophets; even later, readers in the Prophets were allowed to “skip” passages. The synagogue attendant (chazan—v. 20) presumably chose which book to read (different books of the Old Testament were on different scrolls). “Opening” the book meant unrolling the Hebrew scroll to the right place.
> --
> Keener, C. S. (1993). *The IVP Bible background commentary: New Testament* (Lk 4:17). InterVarsity Press.

Answer (score 0):

As one who speaks several Asian languages, I can attest that in this case Greek holds some similarities to them.  For example, the word "find" in English has no true equivalent in these languages in Southeast Asia where it  can *only* mean that one has already encountered the thing.  In English, the word "find" may be synonymous with "seek"--in which case the object sought for is not yet located.  For example, "let's go find some flowers"--the flowers are not yet in hand.  But the Greek word "εὗρεν", here translated as "found", is only used when something is already located.

A sampling of texts where this word is used includes:

> Now the birth of Jesus Christ was on this wise: When as his mother
> Mary was espoused to Joseph, before they came together, she **was
> found G2147** with child of the Holy Ghost. (Matthew 1:18, KJV)
>
> Ask, and it shall be given you; seek, and ye **shall find; G2147**
> knock, and it shall be opened unto you: (Matthew 7:7, KJV)
>
> Who, when he **had found G2147** one pearl of great price, went and
> sold all that he had, and bought it. (Matthew 13:46, KJV)
>
> And he cometh unto the disciples, and **findeth G2147** them asleep,
> and saith unto Peter, What, could ye not watch with me one hour?
> (Matthew 26:40, KJV)
>
> And this shall be a sign unto you; Ye **shall find G2147** the babe
> wrapped in swaddling clothes, lying in a manger. (Luke 2:12, KJV)

Seeing how the word is used in other passages helps us get a sense for its original meaning and application.  It can apply to finding something either with or without intentionally having searched for it.

The custom in those times was that when a rabbi was present at the synagogue, he was expected to deliver the sermon, while any Israelite might give the reading from the prophets.  On this occasion, Jesus was requested to take part, and he was handed a roll of the prophet Isaiah.  It is unclear whether or not the precise passage from that book were assigned to Jesus, or if he were free to select one of his choosing.  In either case, it is certain that his "finding" of the passage which he read had been a directed, intentional outcome, and not one of chance.

**Conclusion**

As the Greek word here indicates, Jesus located the passage in Isaiah, not by mere luck or chance, but almost certainly by intention.  The word "εὗρεν" is used for when the sought-for object is already found, and is not used in Greek for the search phase of the process.

Comment: Gen. 6:8; 16:7; 19:19; 26:12; 30:14; 31:33, 35; 36:24; 37:15, 17; 38:20; 39:4; 44:12, 16; Lev. 5:22-23; 14:22, 30; Num. 31:50; Deut. 22:27; 24:1; Jda. 6:13; 15:15; Jdg. 6:13; 15:15; 1 Sam. 1:18; 14:30; 16:22; 2 Sam. 7:27; 1 Ki. 11:19, 29; 13:14, 24, 28; 2 Ki. 4:39; 10:13, 15; 17:4; 19:8; 23:24; 1 Chr. 17:25; 2 Chr. 22:8; 25:5; 34:14; 35:19; Neh. 9:32; Est. 2:9, 17; 6:2; Prov. 3:13; 18:22; Job 33:10. LXX

Comment: Jon. 1:3; Isa. 59:5; Bar. 3:15, 30; Lam. 1:3; Dat. 1:20; 3:48; Matt. 18:28; 20:6; 21:19; 26:43; Mk. 7:30; 11:13; 14:40; Lk. 4:17; 13:6; 22:45; Jn. 2:14; 11:17; Acts 7:46; 9:33; 2 Tim. 1:17; Heb. 12:17. LXX

Comment: OK. Your answer is consistent with this verb form.